# How do I re-enable Civ 5's opening movie?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I bought Civ 5 and clicked too quickly on the intro video the first time I loaded the game. Now it doesn't play anymore but I would like to see it again. I cannot seem to find where to reset it. I bought the game on Steam and I am on MacOS 10.9 (Mavericks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check in the **options** under **interface options** for **skip intro** checkbar,[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFvcx.png), and make sure it is set as you wish it.

Another way is in the game folder itself,should be **"Steam\steamapps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization V"**.There you can find **Civ5_Opening_Movie_en_US.wmv**.It is simple movie file you can play.

[Or you could simply watch the intro online on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=civ%205%20intro&sm=3)